# testing devise unauthenticated user with cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cucumber, capybara

IN this example: https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-devise-rspec-cucumber

I get an error because doing visit('/users/sign_out') (in capybara..to ensure a user is logged out) fails. The problem is there's no route for a GET to that path, since devise changed it to DELETE(and capybara doesn't support PUT and DELETE without some js workarounds)

What are your suggestions in doing the "Given I am an unauthenticated user" step? how do you guys usually do it? I am hoping there's an easy way out of this like 1-2 lines of ruby.

at the moment, i just do :

```
Given "i am an unauthenticated user" do
  @user == nil
end
```

but it sure doesn't look like it's testing anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah - this has been a bit of a pain for lotsa folks.

The easiest way to get around it is to throw this in your /config/initializers/devise.rb file:

```
  config.sign_out_via = Rails.env.test? ? :get : :delete
```

This will use the old get method for your test environment, and delete for all others.

Comment: would this be better if it was put in config/environments/test.rb? is it possible or is it better to just do the above?

Comment: Yep - putting it in environments/test should work fine as well (config.sign_out_via = :get). Whichever you prefer really. ...And thanks. :-)